# Weird popup on Android 'GNUroot Debian' - what could cause it?

Tags: malware, android

I've got an Android device connected to my TV. The OS itself is of dubious origin, and various tools report it as rooted and unrooted. There's nothing important on its flash memory. Nonetheless, after using GNURoot Debian (think cygwin for android) to do a simple wget, I got this weird popup, see image.
[image: What is this?]

I don't use VNC, and this error puzzles me. Particularly why something would attempt a VNC connection from localhost to localhost. Any ideas?

Edit: I've used this GNURoot Debian (from official Play Store) for a few hours yesterday - without this odd error. There were no other actions inside it, except a simple wget job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am the creator of GNURoot Debian.  GNURoot Debian does use VNC for providing a graphical desktop if desired.  If you click the Xterm icon (maybe on accident in this case), GNURoot Debian starts a VNC Server and then starts and VNC client to connect to it.  This is the error you get if for some reason the server is not running when the client goes to connect to it.
Corbin

Comment: I may have clicked an icon that looked a lot like an XTerm icon. This error happened much later though, perhaps 10-15 minutes. What timeout are you using?

Comment: On a slightly related note for anyone that runs into this problem: After getting this error, whenever I would exit the shell a VNC notification would stay in the background and would persist even after typing "exit" into the terminal emulator. I couldn't figure out how to get rid of it. It went away after restarting the tablet. It turns out it is because I accidentally clicked the Xterm icon.